# xml and php - outputting text

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I need quick help with reading my xml. i am showing my result in a tooltip and everything is ready. I want to query each lot by id one by one. I need a php code to for each lot by their `id` 
Here is my XML

```
<section id="8" number="8" name="Section 8" phase="4" date="2/11/2013">
<lot id="2198" lot="2" block="1" section="8">
<number>2</number>
<legal>L2-B1-S8 (60')</legal>
<address>12107 Arbor Blue Lane</address>
<builder>Perry Homes</builder>
<status>Sold</status>
<plan>3158</plan>
<brick>Acme-StoneBriar</brick>
<trim>SW-Portbello, Tea Chest</trim>
<final_inspection_date/>
<completion>5/23/2013</completion>
<sqft>3158</sqft>
<stories>2</stories>

<bed>4</bed>
<bath>3</bath>
<garage>3</garage>
<lotwidth>60'</lotwidth>
<specprice>Sold</specprice>
<imglocation>none</imglocation>
<premium>off</premium>
</lot>
<lot id="2218" lot="22" block="1" section="8">
<number>22</number>
<legal>L22-B1-S8 (60')</legal>
<address>19503 Bella Arbor Lane</address>
<builder>Perry Homes</builder>
<status>Sold</status>
<plan>3391</plan>
<brick>Hanson-Chestnut Hill</brick>
<trim>SW-Virtual Taupe, Smokehouse</trim>
<final_inspection_date>12/3/2012</final_inspection_date>
<completion>11/28/2012</completion>
<sqft>3391</sqft>
<stories>2</stories>
<bed>4</bed>
<bath>3</bath>
<garage>3</garage>
<lotwidth>60'</lotwidth>
<specprice>Sold</specprice>
<imglocation>3391w-e51.png</imglocation>
<premium>off</premium>
</lot>
</section>
```

Here is my Test php code

```
    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('mydata.xml');

    $xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);

    $queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//lot[@id="2198"]/address'); 
    foreach($queryResult as $result){
            echo $result->textContent;

    }
```

This just gives me the address. How do i get all other attributes listed? that I can now use in my tooltip as this

```
    <div style="float:left">

<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Status: </label>'.$status.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Builder: </label>'.$builder.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width:200px
"><label style="color:grey">Address: </label>'.$address.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Square Ft: </label>'.$square.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Stories: </label>'.$stories.'</p>

<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Completion: </label>'.$completion.'</p>


<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Plan #: </label>'.$plan.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">B/B/G: </label>'.$bed.'/'.$bath.'/'.$garage.'</p>
<p style="
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
"><label style="color:grey">Spec Price: </label>'.$specprice.'</p>


</div>
```

Comment: How about exchanging `/address` to another attribute in your XPath? (or `*` if you want all of them)

Answer (score 0):

```
//lot[@id="2198"]/address
```

You asked: *"This just gives me the address. How do i get all other attributes listed?"*

In Xpath, you can use the star `*` if you don't want to specify the concrete name of the element:

```
//lot[@id="2198"]/*
```

Example: [ZVON Example 3: The star * selects all elements located by preceeding path](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example3.html)

But your question was not exceptionally clear to me, so this answer is a bit of a guess. Don't blame me if it does not help you ;)